# SetPhraseListAsync - Catastrophic failure

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, uwp, cortana

I'm trying to update the phrase lists of my UWP (Windows 10) app, but more than not I get a 'catastrophic failure' with no reason why.

I register Cortana like so in App.xaml.cs

```
StorageFile vcdStorageFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"VoiceCommandDefinition.xml");
await VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(vcdStorageFile);
Debug.WriteLine("Cortana loaded");
```

Then I load my data (it's a Nest thermostat client, so I load the thermostats and structures). After that I try  to update the phrase lists.

```
string thermostatsStrings = "";
string structureStrings = "";
VoiceCommandDefinition commandSetEnUs;
if (VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstalledCommandDefinitions.TryGetValue("Nest_en-us", out commandSetEnUs))
{
    try
    {
        List<Nest.Thermostat> thermostats = GetAllThermostats();
        if (thermostats != null)
        {
            thermostatsStrings = String.Join(", ", thermostats);
            List<String> names = thermostats.Select(thermostat => thermostat.name).ToList();
            await commandSetEnUs.SetPhraseListAsync("nest", names);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.Log("Helpers - UpdatePhraseListThermostat", true, ex.Message + 
            Environment.NewLine + "Thermostats: " + thermostatsStrings + 
            Environment.NewLine + "Structures: " + structureStrings);
    }
    try
    {
        List<Nest.Structure> structures = GetAllStructures();
        if (structures != null)
        {
            structureStrings = String.Join(", ", structures);
            List<String> names = structures.Select(structure => structure.name).ToList();
            await commandSetEnUs.SetPhraseListAsync("place", names);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.Log("Helpers - UpdatePhraseListStructure", true, ex.Message +
            Environment.NewLine + "Thermostats: " + thermostatsStrings +
            Environment.NewLine + "Structures: " + structureStrings);
    }
}
```

My VCD file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
<CommandSet xml:lang="en-US" Name="Nest_en-us">
<AppName> Nest </AppName>
<Example> Open Nest </Example>

<Command Name="RequestTemp">
  <Example>Nest, what is the current temperature </Example>
  <ListenFor> What is [the] {nest} temperature </ListenFor>
  <ListenFor> What is [the] temperature in the {nest} </ListenFor>
  <ListenFor> What is [the] [current] temperature </ListenFor>
  <Feedback> Getting the temperature </Feedback>
  <VoiceCommandService Target="NestCommandService"/>
</Command>

<Command Name="SetHome">
  <Example> Nest, I'm coming home </Example>
  <ListenFor> Set {place} to home </ListenFor>
  <ListenFor> I am on my way to {place} </ListenFor>
  <ListenFor> I am coming home </ListenFor>
  <ListenFor> I am home </ListenFor>
  <ListenFor> set [status] to home </ListenFor>
  <ListenFor> set [state] to home </ListenFor>
  <ListenFor> set [mode] to home </ListenFor>
  <ListenFor> I am back </ListenFor>
  <ListenFor> I am on my way [home] </ListenFor>


  <Feedback> Setting mode to home </Feedback>
  <VoiceCommandService Target="NestCommandService"/>
</Command>


<PhraseList Label="nest">

</PhraseList>

<PhraseList Label="place">

</PhraseList>

</CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

I built in error logging in my app (MetroLog), this is what it logs:

```
2|2016-02-03T15:39:14.0034437+00:00|TRACE|2|Crashes|Helpers - UpdatePhraseListThermostat
Catastrophic failure

Catastrophic failure

Thermostats: Living Room
Structures: 
3|2016-02-03T16:03:32.2687198+00:00|TRACE|2|Crashes|Helpers - UpdatePhraseListStructure
Catastrophic failure

Catastrophic failure

Thermostats: Living Room
Structures: Home
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mishaps in the code. Firstly if you're trying to install the VCD from the app package then the code looks somewhat like this:

```
Uri uriVoiceCommands = new Uri("ms-appx:///VoiceCommandDefinition1.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uriVoiceCommands);
        await VoiceCommandManager.InstallCommandSetsFromStorageFileAsync(file);
```

Secondly, while declaring a phrase list it's not recommended to not insert any element inside the phrase list so initially you must put atleast 1 element. 
Thirdly, The Catastrophic error is maybe because you have a lot of code being run to determine the updation of the VCD, I would rather determine the values to be put in the phrase list in a separate method and then use the following code to update the phrase list dynamically:

```
Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.VoiceCommandSet commandSetEnUs;

    if (Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.VoiceCommandManager.InstalledCommandSets.TryGetValue("AdventureWorksCommandSet_en-us", out commandSetEnUs))
    {
        await commandSetEnUs.SetPhraseListAsync(
          "destination", new string[] { Value1Det, value2Det });   //where Value2Det and Value1Det are the resulted outputs from thermostat 
    }
```